# More succinct way to use shims in variadic templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, shim

C++ templates are generally assimilated to creators of bloat, and the Shim idea deals with exactly that: making the template just a thin wrapper over a regular function. It's a really great way to cut down on the bloat.

For example, let's use a simple shim:

```
//
// Shim interface
//
struct Interface {
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const = 0;
}; // struct Interface

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Interface const& i) {
    i.print(out);
    return out;
}

template <typename T>
struct IT: public Interface {
    IT(T const& t): _t(t) {}
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const { out << _t; }
    T const& _t;
};

template <typename T>
IT<T> shim(T const& t) { return IT<T>(t); }
```

Now, I can use it like so:

```
void print_impl(Interface const& t);

template <typename T>
void print(T const& t) { print_impl(shim(t)); }
```

And no matter how `print_impl` is implemented, `print` remains very lightweight and should be inlined. Easy peasy.

---

C++11 however introduces *variadic* templates. The typical urge then is to reimplement all unsafe C-variadics with C++11 variadic templates, even Wikipedia suggests so with [a `printf` implementation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).

Unfortunately, Wikipedia's implementation does not deal with positional arguments: the kind that allows you to specify print the 3rd parameter there, etc... It would be easy, if only we had a function with this prototype:

```
void printf_impl(char const* format, Interface const* array, size_t size);
```

or similar.

Now, **how do we bridge from the original interface**:

```
template <typename... T>
void printf(char const* format, T const&... t);
```

**to the signature above ?**

One difficulty with the shims is that they rely on the binding to const-ref behavior to extend the lifetime of the temporary wrapper created just enough without having to allocate memory dynamically (they would *not* be cheap if they did).

It seems difficult though to get that binding + the array transformation in one step. Especially because arrays of references (and pointer to references) are not allowed in the language.

---

I have a beginning of a solution, for those interested:

```
//
// printf (or it could be!)
//
void printf_impl(char const*, Interface const** array, size_t size) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i) { std::cout << *(array[i]); }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <typename... T>
void printf_bridge(char const* format, T const&... t) {
    Interface const* array[sizeof...(t)] = { (&t)... };
    printf_impl(format, array, sizeof...(t));
}

template <typename... T>
void printf(char const* format, T const&... t) {
    printf_bridge(format, ((Interface const&)shim(t))...);
}
```

however you will note the introduction of a supplementary step, which is a bit annoying. Still, [it appears to work](http://ideone.com/Mk9Kg).

I would be very grateful if someone had a better implementation to propose.

---

@Potatoswatter suggested using initializer lists, which [helps a bit](http://ideone.com/QLJCQ) (no range-for there).

```
void printf_impl(char const*, std::initializer_list<Interface const*> array) {
    for (Interface const* e: list) { std::cout << *e; }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <typename... T>
void printf_bridge(char const* format, T const&... t) {
    printf_impl(format, {(&t)...});
}
```

But still does not solve the intermediate function issue.

Comment: Oh noes, teh bloats! A few extra KB in my executable is the end of my world.

Comment: @DeadMG this kind of thing really can save megabytes.

Comment: I don't think the member variable `T const& _t;` in `IT` extends the lifetime of the temporary returned from the `shim()` function. When the constructor returns, `_t` refers to the destructed object.

Comment: @Nawaz it's OK, the `IT` must be destroyed before the argument to its constructor anyway.

Comment: Oh.. I misread it. My previous comment doesn't even make sense because of that.

Comment: @DeadMG: well, if you prefer, I could have formulated it in terms of dependency management :) Being able to write `print_impl` in a .cpp means I can avoid pulling it heaps of dependencies in the headers... and this means I save not only some MB in the final binary, I also speed up compilation significantly. But I suppose we don't all work with a few thousands of libraries as *dependencies* ;)

Comment: I already used that concept in a project I did last year, maybe you can find some usefull trick inside, if it is of any use let me know :D

Comment: Jsut out of curiosity you forgot to link the original wikipedia article. anyway I think you are out of luck, my old solution required copy, but you cannot avoid that as long as you want a implementation that takes an array as argument.

Comment: @DarioOO: Avoiding the copy is relatively easy (capture a reference, not a value); avoiding a dynamic memory allocation is harder; Potatoswatter managed it in its answer (which I had forgotten to accept).

Comment: reference is same of a pointer in assembly, instead of passing a value, you then start passing another value (the pointer), wich is used to access indirectly the first value, if you want the ability to conditionally traverse the array (because of the format string), the compiler cannot optimize that by creating an "ad-hoc" version of the function for a particular argument (and I highly doubt the compiler would ever do that even without the format string).. **under the constraint that you want `printf_impl` using an array as parameter** and your types vary in size of course

Comment: For a printing function accepting references only it is viable (all have same size), in the general case no.

Comment: @DarioOO: Indeed, the shim idea probably falls short when there is a need to accept parameters in different modes (`&` and `const&` for example) and even worse when some should be accepted by reference and other copied/moved. Not impossible, per se, but I fear the interface would be ugly (you would have to conditionally check things, etc...). This question, however, is not ambitious enough to venture in such territory :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making it lightweight hinges on eliminating the type parameterization. Your shim potentially instantiates something heavy-duty with the expression `out << _t`, so it might not really be a good example.

C varargs handles the problem by implicitly casting everything to `intptr_t`. If you only want to replicate C `printf` functionality, you can do the same with `reinterpret_cast` and an `initializer_list`.

```
template <typename... T>
void printf(char const* format, T const&... t) {
    printf_impl(format, { reinterpret_cast< std::intptr_t >( t ) ... } );
}
```

This is obviously suboptimal, but shims are inherently limited. You could do something else with polymorphic types in the `initializer_list` if you wanted.

In any case, this is exactly what `initializer_list` is meant for. It can only be constructed from a braced-init-list, making its size a compile-time constant. But the size can only be read back as a runtime constant. So its only practical use is to funnel templates differing only in list length to a common, variable-length implementation.

Add to that the lifetime semantics of `initializer_list` arguments — the objects are created in a contiguous array on the stack and die when the function call statement ends — and `initializer_list` looks a lot like `<varargs>`! (Edit: or your solution, which I have now actually gone back and read :vP )

**Edit:** Since containers can't directly store polymorphic objects, and smart pointers aren't appropriate for temporary argument objects, implementing polymorphism would require taking pointers to temporaries. Ugly, but legal due to the lifetime guaranteed for temporary objects:

```
template <typename... T>
void printf(char const* format, T const&... t) {
    printf_impl(format, std::initializer_list< Interface const * >
        { & static_cast< Interface const & >( shim(t) )... } );
}
```

Comment: The `initializer_list` is nice, unfortunately it does not support references either, because of inner typedefs. Still helps a bit making the code lighter. Do you think `{(&(Interface const&)shim(t))...}` would be valid in `printf` ? ideone errors out on this: "error: conversion from `<brace-enclosed initializer list>` to non-scalar type `std::initializer_list<const Interface*>` requested"

Comment: @MatthieuM. It doesn't support references because it's a container and constructs an array. I don't think there's any solution to the problem that doesn't involve an array (or other container), because what other interface would the non-template implementation accept?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Well, that's probably a bug in G++, because that brace-enclosed-initializer-list *is* convertible to that `initializer_list` specialization. Hmm, I hadn't thought about the problem with polymorphism and containers. Yes, although that should be `static_cast`, I guess that might be the best solution…

Comment: unfortunately I am on a new system and I have not reinstalled the latest gcc and Clang yet there so I can't test with anything more recent than what ideone offers :x Otherwise it would certainly bypass the intermediary function.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use homogenous (same size and alignment in memory) types take a look [at that](https://github.com/Darelbi/Infectorpp2/blob/master/include/Infectorpp/InfectorContainer.hpp):

```
// thin template layer over regular class/methods
template< typename T, typename... Contracts>
inline void Container::bindSingleAs(){

isMultiBase< T, Contracts...>(); //compile time test

    priv::TypeInfoP         types[ sizeof...( Contracts)]
                            { &typeid( Contracts)... };

    priv::SharedUpcastSignature upcasts[ sizeof...( Contracts)]
                            { &priv::shared_upcast< T, Contracts>... };

    // dispatch over non-template method.
    container->bindSingleAs( &typeid(T), types, upcasts, sizeof...(   Contracts));
}
```

**Now after editing due to comments, I think there are 2 conflicting requisites.**

1. Want an array parameter
2. Want no copy overhead

If the `printf_impl` function require an array as parameter, then this mean that the array elements should have the same disposition in memory (that means that if 1 element is 64 bytes that forces all other elements to be 64 bytes aligned even if they are 1 byte..) **hence a copy is necessary**, or at least the copy to a pointer to a fixed location, so it is definitely **NOT POSSIBLE** do what OP wanted.

**We can still build that array but we are constrained**:

1. We Don't want copying at all, then we should statically declare the type of the array, this force us to build a third type.

   `auto Array = MakeArray( /* values*/);`

   `printf( Array);`
2. We accept copying, so we build the array inside the function, since values are not known we can hide array from user but we have to copy the parameters to fixed memory locations, however we still have the array hided under the hood.
3. Heap allocation, that allows to pass parameters in a very compact array, however the parameters have to reside elsewhere and heap allocation may be costly.

The first solution is to accept an extra complexity in coding by creating a statically typed array wich elements can be addressed (all aligned to biggest element), however that is suboptimal since that increase the size of the object wich can hit anyway performance (if that array lives even after the function call)

The second solution hides the complexity behind the template interface, however it cannot avoid the performance cost of copying values temporarily to an array identical to the one of the first solution.

**So, it is not possible doing so, sorry.** The other answer falls between number 2 and 3. All other possible answers would be within one of the 3 categories.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Shim is not a person's name, it's a regular [English word](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shim). The date of question being 2012 should tell you the shim idea is much older than your repository, but to be honest that's completely irrelevant. Nobody cares who invented first (unless patents are involved) the world is full of re-discoveries. I would advise to trim your answer to the relevant parts...

Comment: Ah :) thanks, I trimmed and improved it a little bit, any unclear parts or is it all good to you?

Comment: ... however first the answer would have to be refocused. The question is specifically how to go from `template <typename... T> void printf(char const* format, T const&... args)` to `void print_impl(char const*, Interface const*, size_t)` or `void print_impl(char const*, std::initializer_list<Interface const*>)` without an intermediary step (which is difficult because of the shim inclusion), however this answer does not have a shim to start with, so unless it explain why it can work without a shim (ie, this `Interface` class) or that the shim is a non-issue, it is not addressing the question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll expand that now

Comment: Ok I'm now debuggin the second version of the answer, however it already shows the proof of the concept :).

Comment: Note that for performance reasons, the initial implementation avoided both copies and memory allocation. Otherwise, as demonstrated by your solution, it is trivial.